# How to sort two lists without using inbuild function, Please explain why I am getting this error

Tags: python

Given two lists, The python code should sort first list and then second list and then sort both the list

```
def merge(list_a, list_b):
    
    # Sort first list
    #Used insertion sort 
    for i in range(1, len(list_a)):
        index = list_a[i]
        j=i
        while(j>0 and list_a[j-1]>index):
            list_a[j] = list_a[j-1]
            j = j-1
        list_a[j] = index
    #print(list_a)
        
    # Sort second list
    #Used insertion sort 
    for i in range(1, len(list_b)):
        index = list_b[i]
        j=i
        while(j>0 and list_b[j-1]>index):
            list_b[j] = list_b[j-1]
            j = j-1
        list_b[j] = index
    #print(list_b)  
    
      
    #comparing both the list together
    resultant = []
    k=0
    value = len(list_b)
    #print(value)
    for i in range(len(list_a)):
        for j in range(value+1):
            if list_a[i] > list_b[j]:
                resultant.append(list_b[j])
                list_b.remove(list_b[j])
                value = value - 1
                    
    
    return resultant
```

Error msg

```
>>>  print(merge([1, 4, 5, 7, 9], [2, 3, 6, 8, 10])) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
    if list_a[i] > list_b[j]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Because you're explicitly iterating until `len(list_b) + 1`, which is one too far…?!

Comment: You ran out of items in one of the lists before the other. Please look into pdb, the python debugger

Comment: `for j in range(value):` should work.

Comment: Can you explain what output you're expecting?

Comment: Hi @DarkKnight , The output should like this :
print(merge([1, 4, 5, 7, 9], [2, 3, 6, 8, 10]))
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Where the first list is sorted as well as second list, not we compare those two sorted list and produce the output, (while sorting we do not use any inbuild functions), just like bubble sort/merge sort/insertion sort ..

Comment: Hi @deceze, I dont think I m explicitly iterating but I guess I am changing the range of the for loop before completion of the for loop(I guess) .

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you don't want to use any built-in sort functions and that you want to write your own. OK, so logically there's no need to sort each list before merging them. You can merge them and sort afterwards because it amounts to the same thing but is more efficient. Therefore, you could do this:-

```
def bubble(L):
    e = len(L)
    while e > 1:
        es = 0
        for i in range(e-1):
            if L[i] > L[i+1]:
                L[i], L[i+1] = L[i+1], L[i]
                es = i+1
        e = es
    return L

def merge(list_a, list_b):
    return bubble(list_a + list_b)

print(merge([1, 4, 5, 7, 9], [2, 3, 6, 8, 10]))
```

Comment: Thank you that might work but, can we compare two lists with out combining them?(like merge(list_a, list_b)) and compare one element of list_a with entire elements of list_b( list_a[i] and list_b[i], list_a[i] and list_b[j], ......)

Comment: Yes - For example *if list_a[I] in list_b* is probably the construct you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

def merge(list_a, list_b):

```
# Sort first list
#Used insertion sort 
for i in range(1, len(list_a)):  
    index = list_a[i]    
    j=i       
    while(j>0 and list_a[j-1]>index):   
        list_a[j] = list_a[j-1]   
        j = j-1    
    list_a[j] = index  
#print(list_a)
    
# Sort second list
#Used insertion sort 
for i in range(1, len(list_b)):  # iterate through the length of the list b
    index = list_b[i]   # fixing the first value to the index as max
    j=i                # seting the value of the j as i 
    while(j>0 and list_b[j-1]>index):  #Comparing i and i+1th element
        list_b[j] = list_b[j-1]  # swaping the lowest element to the first place fo soted list
        j = j-1
    list_b[j] = index  #changing the max element as recent highest element
#print(list_b)  

  
#comparing both the list together
n = len(list_a)
m = len(list_b)
res = [0 for i in range(n+m)] # setting the length of the resultant array and placing it 0 on every element
i,j,k = 0,0,0  # setting a temp values of the size
while (i < n and j < m):    # checking the elements in the range of i and j 
    if (list_a[i] <= list_b[j]):  # checking if list_a has the highest element
        res[k] = list_a[i]   #replacing 0 with the element 
        i += 1  # increaig the length of the temp list 
        k += 1  # increasing the length of the temp list
    else:
        res[k] = list_b[j]  # checking if list_b has the highest element
        j += 1  # incresing  the length of the list
        k += 1  # increasing the length of the list 
         
while (i < n):  # Merging remaining elements of list_a[] (if any)
    res[k] = list_a[i] 
    i += 1
    k += 1
     
while (j < m):  # Merging remaining elements of list_b[] (if any)
    res[k] = list_b[j]
    j += 1
    k += 1
return res
```

Output:

print(merge([1,4,5,7,9] , [2,3,6,8,10]))

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]